# Android: how to get gps location in fragment

Tags: java, angular, gps, fragment

I'm trying to access my current GPS location in a fragment. I don't want to use google map.

It is just a simple fragment with a button and text view. What I would like is to display my current Longitude and Latitude if I press the button.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Hi, did you find how to get this done?